# How to display HStack element based on a conditional in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, conditional-statements, hstack

How do I test a condition within an HStack to determine how it should be displayed? The following code draws a 3x3 grid made from HStack of HStack.

```
var body: some View {
    ForEach(0..<3) { v in
        Spacer()
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<3) { h in
                Spacer()
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    let x = v * 3 + h
                    Text("\(x)").font(.largeTitle)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.yellow)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I do something like:

```
if x % 2 == 0 { // if even number
    .background(.yellow)
} else {
    .background(.blue)
}
```

Where do I even stick such a code within the HStack (or any other SwiftUI object)'s declarative statements?

Comment: Shouldn't the view be built as 3 x `HStack` inside a `VStack`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator is recommended in this case, `?` represents `if` and `:` represents `else`

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(0..<3) { v in
            Spacer()
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<3) { h in
                    Spacer()
                    let x = v * 3 + h
                    Text("\(x)").font(.largeTitle)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .background(x % 2 == 0 ? .yellow : .blue)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

The inner `HStack` is redundant and you need an enclosing `VStack`.

Or without the `Spacer`s

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(0..<3) { v in
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0..<3) { h in
                    let x = v * 3 + h
                    Text("\(x)").font(.largeTitle)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .background(x % 2 == 0 ? .yellow : .blue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(8)
}
```

Comment: It says "Cannot find 'x' in scope. I declared x outside the var body:
var x : Int
but that doesn't work either. I get "Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Spacer' conform to 'TableRowContent'" for the Spacer().

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help in providing a working solution. Meanwhile, I've been reading up on "Conditional View Modifiers." Lots to learn.

Comment: Avoid conditional modifiers as much as possible. They can break animations.

Comment: Yeah, I read about that in https://www.objc.io/blog/2021/08/24/conditional-view-modifiers/, but the author didn't provide better alternatives to solving the problem. Or maybe they are saying it's OK, do it, as long as it doesn't involve animations.